# Looking for paper "The cyclotomic identity" by Metropolis and Rota

Tags: co.combinatorics, reference-request

I am looking for a copy of the paper in the title, appeared in the proceedings

"Combinatorics and algebra (Boulder 1983), Contemp. Math., 34"

and reprinted in

"Gian-Carlo Rota on Combinatorics, Birkhäuser, 1995".

I have no way to get it.
Does anyone have a scanned copy of it ? Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: You can see it in http://books.google.co.in/books?hl=en&lr=&id=2axt00oBDEwC&oi=fnd&pg=PA19&ots=I82rYFT1vq&sig=OyshM1vJbnm61VrTahSpNQRhGZE#v=onepage&q&f=false



Comment: That's right, but I can't take it along in the train.

Comment: Matthieu, this will help you retrieve and print it: http://www.aboutonlinetips.com/google-books-downloader/

Comment: Wow ! Thanks Anthony, I didn't know those tricks. However, none seems to work for me : either because the links are off, or because they suggest solutions for Windows users, but I'm on Linux and I can't "translate" the procedure.